# OpenLDAP Give Group Write Access

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, openldap, slapd

Our openldap has multiple groups: useradmins, agt, ib, iss, itt

The "useradmins" group has always had permissions to edit (write) to all of the groups.  I recently performed a simple 'yum update' and openldap was updated.  Since that time (about 3 days ago now) admins cannot write (add or change users).  The error is:

Insufficient access - no write access to parent

...or, depending upon my trial/error with the slapd.conf file, sometimes I simple get:

Insufficient access

I have edited my slapd.conf file (about 500 times) trying different settings while reading online posts, docs, etc.  My current slapd.conf file looks like this:

```
...
database        bdb
suffix          "dc=am5up,dc=com"
directory       /var/lib/ldap

index objectClass                       eq,pres
index ou,cn,mail,surname,givenname      eq,pres,sub
index uidNumber,gidNumber               eq,pres
index uid,memberUid                     eq,pres,sub
index nisMapName,nisMapEntry            eq,pres,sub
index entryCSN                          eq
index entryUUID                         eq

access to *
          by self write
          by dn="cn=admin,dc=am5up,dc=com" write
          by group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember="cn=useradmins,ou=groups,dc=am5up,dc=com" write
          by * read
rootdn    "cn=admin,dc=am5up,dc=com"
rootpw    <hashed pwd>
...
```

My assumption is this line is wrong:

```
group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember="cn=useradmins,ou=groups,dc=am5up,dc=com" write
```

...but I have tried dozens of variations without success.

Can anyone make any suggestions?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Please post the contents of group dn "cn=useradmins,ou=groups,dc=am5up,dc=com" also?

Comment: Anirudh, is this what you are wanting?

dn: cn=useradmins,ou=groups,dc=am5up,dc=com
cn: useradmins
gidnumber: 10001
memberuid: mscot
memberuid: nhman
memberuid: taden
memberuid: japid
objectclass: posixGroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, According to the comment the group is as follows:

> dn: cn=useradmins,ou=group,dc=am5up,dc=com
>
> cn: useradmins
>
> gidnumber: 10001
>
> memberuid: mscot
>
> objectclass: posixGroup
>
> memberuid: nhman
>
> memberuid: taden
>
> memberuid: japid

but according to acl:

> by group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember="cn=useradmins,ou=groups,dc=am5up,dc=com" write

The group should have objectClass groupOfUniqueNames and uniqueMember(whoever you want to grant access to). But the group as shown above doesn't have any, So you can do two things now:

- Add objectClass **groupOfUniqueNames** and its members **uniqueMember**, the ACL will work surely.

OR

- After doing some research I found posixGroup has syntax like this only, You can use  to grant access to posixGroup members. You have to do something like:

> ```
> access to *
>            whatever you want
>            by set="user/uid & [cn=useradmins]/memberuid" write
>            by * none
> ```

For "**user/uid**" this will be applicable if the memberuids are the actual uid of members, otherwise put whatever attribute you are using.